# The sizeof several casts

Tags: c++, casting, sizeof

Why does the function `sizeof` not return the same size when its getting used on the `struct` itself?

I need to cast it because of a winsock program that im working on.
Thanks for any help, true.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct stringstruct
{
    string s1;
    string s2;
};
int main()
{
    stringstruct ss = {"123","abc"};
    char *NX = (char*)&ss;
    cout << sizeof(NX) << endl << sizeof(*NX) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(&ss) << endl << sizeof(ss) << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

the example above outputs

```
4
1
4
64
```

Comment: Because pointers generally have a different size from their pointees?

Comment: Just a hint: If you attempt to send a `std::string` over a network (or anything else) it will not work as you expect. It will not send the actual string in the object, just the object (which contains a _pointer_ to the actual string).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sizeof` will tell you the size of the given expression's type. In both the `sizeof(NX)` and `sizeof(&ss)`, the result is 4 because pointers on your machine take up 4 bytes. For `sizeof(*NX)`, you are dereferencing a `char*`, which gives you a `char`, and a `char` takes up 1 byte (and always does), so you get the output 1. When you do `sizeof(ss)`, `ss` is a `stringstruct`, so you get the size of a `stringstruct`, which appears to be 64 bytes.

Comment: So how to get the sizeof the variables? (The space that the instances are using)

Comment: Which variable? The size of `ss` is `sizeof(ss)`.

Comment: Can't you get the size from ss from NX?

Comment: @true No, because it's a `char*`. But if you know that it's really pointing at a `stringstruct`, then all you need is the size of a `stringstruct`.

Answer (score 2):

```
stringstruct ss = {"123","abc"};
char *NX = (char*)&ss;
cout << sizeof(NX) << endl << sizeof(*NX) << endl;
cout << sizeof(&ss) << endl << sizeof(ss) << endl;
```

I'm pretty sure that any of these casts are pretty meaningless. `NX` will point at the beginning of your struct. Inside the struct are two objects of type `string`, which in turn have pointers pointing to the data they were initialized with `"123"` and `"abc"` respectively. `sizeof(*NX)` is just that - size of a `char`, and `sizeof(NX)` is indeed the size of a pointer. `sizeof(ss)` is the size of your two string members (and any padding added by the compiler) - and `sizeof(&ss)` is the size of a pointer to a stringstruct.

Now, I expect what you REALLY want is a way to send your data, `"123"` and `"abc"` as two separate strings over a network. None of the above will help you do that, since even if `sizeof(ss)` gives you the size of the data structure you want to send, the string values are not within that structure [1]. What you really need is something calls serialization - something that writes out your strings as separate elements as text/string.

Something like this would work:

```
struct stringstruct {
    string s1;
    string s2;
    string to_string()
}

string stringstruct::to_string()
{
   string res = s1 + " " + s2; 
   return res;
}
```

Then use `to_string` like this:

```
string temp = ss.to_string();
const char *to_send = temp.c_str();
int send_len = temp.length();
... send the string `to_send` with number of bytes `send_len`.
```

[1] There is an optimization where `std::string` is actually storing short strings within the actual class itself. But given a sufficiently long strong, it won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is of size 4(in your case seems to be 32 bit) no matter what it points. Size of the object itself on the other hand returns the real number of bytes that an object of that structure takes.

Comment: Well, my system is 64bit. I just compiled in 32.

Comment: Corrected. I have changed my wording there.